# How we can send small form in Email using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I create small form (Name, email, Subject, Message) in Flash. Want to send this by email using AS3 code.

Can we use this offline? Like, we fill all the detail and after submit then its go online and receive the detail in email

Comment: Yes, you can make a call to your webserver running a PHP/ASP script that sends the email even though your flash file is local. You probably have to make sure that crossdomain policies are allowed, however.

Answer (score 1):

as @esimov said, security is not major concern then you have to use [SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27), because your mail send in pure text form to the e-mail server. but if you want to use SMTPMailer then you can use some encryption and decryption method in it. This encryption packet with key are traceable. so If security is major concern then you must use [airxmail](http://code.google.com/p/airxmail/) written in actionscript so you can send and receive mail with SMTP, POP3, IMAP4 protocol. [best example are given to send and recieve a mail](http://flex.coltware.com/as3-flex-air/airxmail/).

May this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use an email client directly using Flash technology you need to stick with Flex. It has a robust backend interaction and even more it allows to do some cross scripting interactions.

However if you wish to use Flash and not Flex, actually there is an email sending application called [SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27) which sends attached files through emails with the Socket class available in the Player 9 and AS3. Please note, that for security reason is always better to send emails from the server side of the application. So another possibility would be to integrate the email sending part in a server side script.